# How do you convert a .PNG image to a matrix of values using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to convert a .PNG image to an array of numerical values (e.g. red, green, blue values) that I can work with using MATLAB?  If so, how can I do this?

Comment: An image **is** numbers. You can not convert an apple to an apple. It is already an apple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what you mean.
if you import `imread('someImage.png')` you get a `n x m x 3`matrix